# Using a 'Using' with a new DataRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I've tried something like this:

```
 using (DataRow newRow = summary.NewRow())
    {
        summary.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
```

But it doesnt work.  I get the error:

> 'System.Data.DataRow': type used in a using statement must be
>   implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Could someone explain to me why I'm unable to dispose the DataRow like this and/or a similar way of doing something like this?  Thanks.

Comment: `using` is a keyword to dispose IDisposables. What do you want it to do with `DataRow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some object to be used inside the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block, it **must implement** [IDisposable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx). [`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) doesn't implement IDisposable and that is why you are getting the error. Not really sure why you want to dispose the DataRow in first place.

[using statement C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

EDIT: *(for comment that you want to reuse the New Row)*

You shouldn't. DataTable stores reference of the new row, using the newely created row again will cause you an exception that row alread exists in the datatable, so for adding a row you always want to create a new row using `DataTable.NewRow` method.

Comment: Because I wanted to use the name newRow again for another DataRow and I thought it might be an idea to put it within a Using.  I'm not saying that was necessarily a good idea, but I just wanted an explanation of why I couldn't do this.

Comment: @Simon, you couldn't do it because `DataRow` doesn't implement IDisposable and you don't have to reuse the New Row since its reference will be stored in the table, so you almost, always wants a new row when adding to the data table.

Comment: @Simon You can use the same name `newRow` again. You need to refresh your knowledge on references, and passing objects to/from methods.

Comment: Yep, I see what you mean.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The object provided to the using statement must implement the IDisposable interface. This interface provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's resources.

`DataRow` doesn't provide `Dispose()` method.

Now, when you are adding new `DataRow`, you don't need to dispose it (nor you can), because `Rows.Add` is actually storing reference to the new row, and not the copy of the object. So, just create your row and pass it to the `Add()` method of `DataRowCollection`, you don't need to do any disposing on the new row.

Based on your comments: When you pass your reference to the `Add()` method, copy of the reference will be stored in the table. After that, you may freely use the same reference to create the new object and to store reference again. `Dispose()` method is used mostly for freeing unmanaged resources:

> Use this method to close or release unmanaged resources such as files, streams, and handles held by an instance of the class that implements this interface. By convention, this method is used for all tasks associated with freeing resources held by an object, or preparing an object for reuse.

If your object doesn't hold any unmanaged resources, you don't need to free it explicitly (unlike C or C++) - when the object can't be referenced (when the count of the references pointing to that object goes to zero) garbage collector will take care of it, and it will delete it automatically (not necessarily immediately) at some point.

Answer (score 1):

From [`using Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

---

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and
>   instantiate it in a using statement.

[`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) class doesn't implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface, that's why you are getting this error.

The `using` statement is combined with a type that implements `IDisposable`. Which class do you want to implement to it, it **must** implements the `IDisposable` interface and the require `Dispose` method also.

For example;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(YourClass y = new YourClass())
        {

        }
    }
}

class YourClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The using block needs to be able to access the method IDisposable.Dispose when the block scope ends.  Therefore your object must state that it implements this interface to be 'using' compatible.

Answer (score 0):

`DataRow` is not disposable, so you simply do not need to do this, and the compiler helps: it won't even let you, because the type doesn't follow the required pattern (i.e. that it should implement `IDisposable`, as per the error message).

If the point is that you want to use `newRow` again, then there's a misconception here. Whether something is disposable or not is irrelevant in this case, and in this context both can be freely 'overwritten':

```
DataRow newRow; // null;
newRow = summary.NewRow(); // get a row
newRow = anotherSummary.NewRow() // get a different row
```

In the above case, after the second assignment, `newRow` forgets all about it's first assignment.

Where disposability plays into this is that you should be careful not to just 'forget' things when they *are* disposable (because you're responsible for disposing them), but in this case you need not worry about that.